# How can one prove that an operation $*$ over a group $Z$ is associative if there are multiple solutions to it?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given that an operation $*$ is applied over the group Z (the group of integers), and $\forall  a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$, the following is true:

$if \space a < 0,\space then \space \space a * b = b$ 
$ if \space a >= 0, \space then \space \space a * b = a$

My idea was to use the possible solutions that the two expressions can have. For the first expression, the solution of $(a * b) * c$, is equal to one of the followings:

(1) $a * c$ 
(2) $b * c$

Therefore, all of the possible solutions of (1) and (2) are [a, c, b, c]. As we reapeat the proccess with the second expression $a * (b * c)$, we get [a, b, a, c]. The probability to get 'c' in the first expression $(a * b) * c$ was higher (2 / 4) than the probability to get 'c' in the other one (1 / 4). Therefore, the operation over the group, is not associative. Or more accurate, the solutions lists were not equal.

This question is part of University homework of a beginners Mathematics course, and I'll be glad to learn from you **what are the additional ways to think about the challenge ?**, and NOT to know the solution to it.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if that operation is associative? Why not work some examples to get a sense?  Why would you think that probability was involved?  If you believe that it is not associative, the best argument is to exhibit three integers $a,b,c$ such that $(a*b)*c\neq a*(b*c)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would complete this table and check whether the last two columns are identical

```
 a<0?  b<0? a*b  b*c (a*b)*c a*(b*c)    
  T     T    b    c      c     c     
  T     F    b 
  F     T    a  
  F     F    a
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful. @Henry